# Defects of smart glass (electrochromic glass)?

Tags: optical-materials, glass

Smart glass is a type of glass that uses electrochromic mechanism to change it's light transmission properties in response to voltage, and it's made by sandwiching certain materials between two panes of glass.

My question is:

Is the electrochromic glass at it's transparent state more transparent than a normal glass? Why?

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be. Electrochromic glass is made by coating electrochromically active films onto an electrochromically inert glass substrate. As such, changes in the electrochromic state only affect the transparency of these added layers, and the base transmission of the underlying glass in unchanged.